# Trying to pass value from ASP.NET JavaScript script to my C# Hidden Field

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I have a JavaScript script inside my ASP.NET Web site, and I want to get a value from a function to my C# backend, using an argument I pass it from my ASP.NET Hidden Field.

Here is my ASP.NET & JavaScript code, I define a HiddenField and assigns the `chatMessage` var to it, then assign a value to the var, and try to send its value to the `returnLiClass()` function.
(Most relevant are lines 1, 13, 14, 17):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="chatMessage" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message.
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div /> ').text(message).html();
            var tremp_id = $('<div /> ').text("<%=Request.QueryString["trempid"]%>").html();

            var chatMessage = document.getElementById('<%= chatMessage.ClientID %>');
            chatMessage.value = 'value from javascript';

            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li class="<%=returnLiClass(chatMessage.Value)%><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + "Tremp:" + tremp_id + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val('<%=returnName()%>');
        // Set initial focus to message input box.
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The backend function (when I debug neither `msg` nor the `chatMessage.Value` have values):

```
protected String returnLiClass(String msg)
{
    String test = chatMessage.Value;
    return "redChat";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Server function will only execute before HTML is sent to the client. To execute a server function with JS use ajax. Check out [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).